# Submit form using external button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

In the view, external to the form, I have a stock "Update" button. Nothing happens when I click the button. Please help. Thank you so much.

```
(haml)
  %button#update_button(type="submit) Update

The call for the form:
  = form_for @employee, id: 'employee-update-form' do |f|
    ...

And the JS intended to submit the form:
:javascript
  $('#update_button').click(function() {
    $('#employee-update-form').submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "PATCH",
        url: '#{employee_path(@employee)}'
        data: $('#employee-update-form').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON"
      }).success(function(json) {
      });
      return false; // prevents normal behavior
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have binded your ajax request to the form on submit event, you'll still need to call the `submit()` to trigger the event.

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ma9kLm34/

Trigger submit after your binding call.

```
$('#employee-update-form').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

call submit method on form

```
$('#employee-update-form').submit();
```

Comment: it is not submitting the form, it is just like on submit yo run the function, so u need to call submit method superately i think so

Comment: Not an ajax solution, but it works for normal behavior. Thanks.